# Installing the newest version of Libertinus Math

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math, math-fonts

The current version of the font Libertinus Math installed with my texlive distribution misses a glyph for `\twoheadrightarrow`. Newer versions of Libertinus Math obtained from the [Github repository](https://github.com/alif-type/libertinus) do contain this glyph, so I would like to install this.

I use the following with XeLaTex, to use the Libertinus font:

```
% set fonts
\usepackage{fontspec, unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
```

I installed the new Math font as a (user) system font, and I replaced `/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/libertinusmath-regular.otf` with the new `.otf`-file. The latter enabled me to use `\setmathfonnt{libertinusmath-regular.otf}` to use the new font file, but if I use `Libertinus Math` it still loads the old fonts, so I cannot use `\twoheadrightarrow`.

So where is `Libertinus Math` actually stored?

Comment: compile with lualatex and look in the log-file, or use \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 and again the log-file

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That works, thanks! If you want, submit an answer with this, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with lualatex and look in the log-file, or use `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` and again look in the log-file. There should be absolute pathes there.